# are general assumptions in simple or passive way?

Tags: past-participles, lists

If I want to say a general assumption in my process, then should it be in simple present tense or passive form like

> 1. Small segments *locate* isolated or close to each other are taken and updated their label.
> 2. Small segments *located*, *isolated* or close to each other are taken and updated their label.
>      Then which form should we generally choose?

Here, can I use ***isolated*** as a noun?

Comment: I'm not really sure of your intended meaning. Feasibly it's what I might phrase as *Small segments, either isolated or close to each other, are processed, and their labels updated.* But it looks pretty close to proofreading. Anyway, it's unlikely you could use ***isolated*** as a noun in your context.

Comment: You have other grammatical errors that make it difficult to understand what you're asking (particularly **are taken and updated their label**, which doesn't parse).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thats fine, I got, what I can not figure out was as some general things are not done by our selves, are not normally written in passive (i guess). with your constructions, I found the way to express.. as it omit the locate or are located... thanks

Comment: @gnp: Do you mean you started with something like *We take segments (either isolated, or in small close-knit groups) and update their labels*, which you then wanted to convert to passive voice? I'm still not clear on how the title relates to the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: no no, sorry for making confuse..I wanted to avoid the word locate because I am not clear that the sentence should be written in active or passive. However, I think your suggestion is very good as it is clear and avoided the locate as well. thanks again.

Comment: The passive voice uses a verb in *participle* form, which is a form that functions like an adjective.  It's not usually considered a noun, so people are confused.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure without better knowledge of the process you are describing; but it appears that you are trying to combine three propositions into one sentence:

1. You select ("take") certain small segments.
2. These segments may be isolated or may lie close to each other.
3. You update the labels on these segments.

If this is the case, it may be expressed in either the active or the passive voice.

> ACTIVE: We select certain small segments, [which may be]* isolated or close to each other, and update their labels.
>   PASSIVE: Certain small segments, [which may be]* isolated or close to each other, are selected and their labels are updated.

*The phrase in brackets may be omitted.

This assumes that the reason for selecting these segments is not expressed within the sentence at hand. However, if what you mean is that you select these segments **because** they are isolated or close to each other, you should express that part somewhat differently. There is no need to say that the segments are selected if you define the selecting principle.

> ACTIVE: We update the labels of small segments which are isolated or lie close to each other.
>   PASSIVE:  The labels of small segments which are isolated or close to each other are updated.

Note that the relative clause *which ... other* is not bracketed with commas. This marks the clause as *restrictive*, meaning that you are speaking about only segments of that kind.

Technical writing of this sort generally prefers a passive, which gives an air of 'impersonality' to your writing.